# Using Excel's Structured Referencing syntax to refer to the "above row?" or "above above row?"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know that I can use [@**col1**] to refer to the cell within **col1** that is on the same row as the formula. But is there a way to refer to the cell that is on the row above? Maybe something like: [@**col1** - 1] (hypothetical)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=INDEX([col2],ROW()-2)
```

In the first table row, the formula will return a 'wrong' value, i.e. the value of the same row, but in the next row it will show correctly.

If you want to calculate a running total, you can use something along the lines of

```
=SUM([@col1],INDEX(C:C,ROW()-1))
```

Note how the reference for Index is the whole column. Using Sum() will ignore text, so the formula will not return an error when the column title is involved.

[image]

Comment: This works perfect if the table starts at A1. But I realize if table is moved around the sheet, then it doesn't work anymore because ROW() gives absolute row#, and [col1] requires relative reference. EX: row # 3 in [col1] may actually be in row# 67 in the excel sheet.

Comment: If your table does not start in row 1, then yes, you'll have to adjust the ROW() function. You can use `ROW()-2` to subtract two rows from the row number. If your table starts in row 100, you may need to subtract 100 from the ROW() function. Think it through. It's simple arithmetic.  Theoretically, you could use `ROW(A1)` to return a 1, and when the formula is copied down it changes to `ROW(A2)`, but experience shows that structured referencing does not mix well with cell addresses. In a structure reference, the formula for the whole column must be the same and you can do that with `ROW()-54`.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you distance of the row you're on from the header row, and handles the first row with no problem.

```
=(ROW() - ROW([#Headers])-1)
```

Easy to adapt for use with `OFFSET` or `INDEX` to give you the previous row.

Comment: this worked as a charm, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there is a built in way, but you can always index match.  Something like

```
=INDEX(A:A, MATCH([@Col1],A:A, 0)-1)
```

Change the A:A to whatever column you want to reference and -1 for one row up, -2 for two rows up, and so on.

Comment: That will only work if the values in `Col` are unique.